# Add a Comment Table View Like Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, instagram

I am making a comments section for my app. The comments are loaded from the server vs MYSQL and PHP and JSON. Once they are loaded, they are put into a table view, sort of like Instagram displays comments. The thing is that I'm not sure how to make the table view. I have loaded the comments in the table view, but now I need to add the part where the user can add a new comment. I am stuck on the UI part of this. In Instagram, the add comment section is always in the bottom, the last row of the table view. Once you comment, the table view is expanded and the comment is added. I'm not sure how to develop a user interface for this. How can I make sure that the very bottom of the page has a separate row, which displays my custom table view cell, which I can use to add the comment?

Edit: Table View Footer doesn't product the right results for me. 
I tried to do this: 
http://gyazo.com/4a30bf09cb5186c649a55af6bb889a76 
and got this.
 http://gyazo.com/d524d85eeb10d1eec3eb5253a8769ba6
 This is not correct, as it is not at the bottom of the screen, just where the table view is. I want it to always be in the bottom.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a footer to your `UITableView` which will have your view that has the comment `UITextField` and `UIButton`.

To add a footer to your `UITableView`, implement the following method in the `UITableView's` delegate:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

It will return the view you want to use as your footer (your UIView with your UITextField, etc).

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForFooterInSection:

Comment: I tried to do this: http://gyazo.com/4a30bf09cb5186c649a55af6bb889a76 and got this. http://gyazo.com/d524d85eeb10d1eec3eb5253a8769ba6 This is not correct, as it is not at the bottom of the screen, just where the table view is. I want it to always be in the bottom.